# Creating a Path Variable

Tags: environment-variables, paths

I need to set a path for a variable $week4 to be Week4/assignment so that typing cd $week4 will change the working directory to Week4/assignment/

I've seen a few examples of similar stuff on here, but I haven't been able to make it work for me.  Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Since your path has spaces in it you need to enclose both the path AND the variable in `""`. Try this from the command line.

```
export week4="/home/Justin/Week 4/assignment/"
```

Now you should be able to navigate to that directory by typing cd `$week4`

If you want to make this permanent then add the same line to your `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you can add following in your `~/.bashrc` file .

```
  WEEK=/path/of/your/dir/
```

Open `~/.bashrc` file using `gedit ~/.bashrc` and add above in it an save it.

Now you can use `cd $WEEK` to cd your folder

Comment: when I try to access my ~/.bashrc, I get a "permission denied" mesage.  I tried typing WEEK4=mypath in my home directory home/Justin and it was accepted.  However, when I went to type "cd $WEEK4" it got the message saying no such directory

Comment: Have you changed the permission or owner of ~/.bashrc file?. And for the second part of your question, use `WEEK=/home/Justin/Week4/assignment/` if  /Week4/assignment/ directory is in your home folder.

Comment: For the second part, I typed the full path which was "week4=Linux Programming 1/Week4/Assignments" and it was accepted.  (Yes this is a homework assignment).  Linux Programming 1 is a directory located in my home folder.  When I went to then type "cd $week4" I got an error message saying no directory

Comment: As your path contain space. Either remove space or use command in following ways. `week4="Linux Programming 1/Week4/Assignments"` and for cd `cd "$week4"`

Comment: Hmmm, still didn't work.  I must be doing something wrong